# bigquery google.api.client get tables list API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-js-client

I need to get all tables list from the dataset, but now the return result having only 50 items in the table array, the totalItems having 56 tables.

**How can I get all tables without giving the maxResult param value in the request?**

```
var query = gapi.client.request({
    'method':'GET',      
'path':'bigquery/v2/projects/'+projectid+'/datasets/msm_weekly_report/tables'

    });
```

If I use `'path':'bigquery/v2/projects/'+projectid+'/datasets/{DATA_SET}/tables?maxResults={count}'` I am getting all tables in the response.
is there any other way to get all tables without passing maxResults, because the dataset will be updating each week, so we can't give correct count dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As I could tested [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/list), we could retrieved all the tables by specifying `maxResults` to a large number. In my case, I have 8 tables in the dataset and I have specified `maxResults` to 200 (retrieving 8 tables).

IMHO, you can set `maxResults` to a large enough number to ensure to retrieve all your tables when updated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. my dataset will be creating a table in each week and I need to fetch last updated table to visualize, now I am making first API call to get the total count of tables and then taking that count as the maxResults input value, Again making the API call.

Comment: In this case you only want to retrieve the last updated table. I don't understand why you need to get all the tables. I would say you should play with the new `tablename` if the last updated table is the new table created in the last week. Anyway, this should be different question with more details so the people can post an answer for that.